# linux: watchdog node is not created in /dev directory

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, bsp

I want to use a watchdog timer in my application.

I am using the yocto build system on the msm8953 platform.

As per compatible field in `.dtsi` file, corresponding driver configured in `.defconfig` file(i.e. `CONFIG_MSM_WATCHDOG_V2 = y`) and I am getting following dmesg:

```
[ 0.270444] msm_watchdog b017000.qcom,wdt: wdog absent resource not present
[ 0.270845] msm_watchdog b017000.qcom,wdt: MSM Watchdog Initialized
```

But, watchdog node is not created in `/dev` directory.

I have also configured WATCHDOG and WATCHDOG_CORE driver as default in Kconfig file, but still the watchdog node is not present in `/dev` directory.

Edit 1: added default value as Y in /drivers/watchdog/Kconfig

menuconfig WATCHDOG

bool "Watchdog Timer Support"

**default Y**

if WATCHDOG

config WATCHDOG_CORE

bool "WatchDog Timer Driver Core"

**default Y**

Comment: Can you share the contents of the following file in the linux kernel `linux/drivers/watchdog/Kconfig`

Comment: @SantoshA, please find Edit 1 section in the post for the changed content of Kconfig file.

Comment: Read `/proc/config.gz` to check the actual kernel configuration.

Comment: Can you just create the devnode file by hands ? (mknod)

Comment: @AlexHoppus, I created watchdog node in dev directory using mknod. But, when i 
 am opening that node , "watchdog: No such device" error occured.

Comment: Are you sure that major minor number were specified correctly?

Comment: @AlexHoppus, i created watchdog node using "mknod -m 777 watchdog c 10 130" this command , and but open system call fail with "watchdog: No such device" error

Comment: Are you using udev?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the code from [here](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/msm/+/android-5.1.0_r0.6/arch/arm/mach-msm/msm_watchdog_v2.c). My answer is based on this code.

A device driver can generate a node on `/dev` and also on `/sys`. So we have to check about both `/sys` and `/dev`.

**About nodes on /sys**

There are many functions to create a node on `/sys`. One of the functions is `device_create_file()`.
In [this code](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/msm/+/android-5.1.0_r0.6/arch/arm/mach-msm/msm_watchdog_v2.c), if `init_watchdog_work()` is called and `device_create_file()` is called, watchdog's node, `disable` would be created by this code.

```
error = device_create_file(wdog_dd->dev, &dev_attr_disable);
```

You can find the `disable` node in msm watchdog directory.
And you can find msm watchdog directory using `find`.

```
find /sys -name '*watchdog*'
```

Even if your code is different with [this](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/msm/+/android-5.1.0_r0.6/arch/arm/mach-msm/msm_watchdog_v2.c), maybe you can see that `device_create_file()` is called in watchdog driver.
Thus, you can find a node as I said.

**About nodes on /dev**

Generally, you can use `device_create()` to create a node on `/dev`. If `device_create()` is called, a node is created on `/dev`, otherwise it is not created.

[msm_rotator](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/msm/+/android-5.1.0_r0.6/drivers/char/msm_rotator.c) driver creates `msm_rotator` node on `/dev`.

```
#define DRIVER_NAME "msm_rotator"
...
msm_rotator_dev->device = device_create(msm_rotator_dev->class, NULL,
                    msm_rotator_dev->dev_num, NULL,
                    DRIVER_NAME);
```

If `device_create()` is called in your code, you can find the node on `/dev`. If the function is not called, there is not a node on `/dev`.

Comment: author has asked about devnode, not about sysfs entry

Comment: @AlexHoppus I updated my answer to give explanation about a node on `/dev`.

Comment: @HyeongnamJang, when i enable Softdog driver then watchdog node is created in dev directory. Will softdog reset the system using hardware watchdog? How can i validate that my system is reset by hardware watchdog?

Comment: @kripalsinhrana, First, please tell me more about softdog driver. This driver is provided by qualcomm or codeaurora? Second, for check your system is reset by HW watchdog, the best way is to check PON reason in kernel log, I think. Please refer to [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-6p/help/dev-help-debugging-ramoops-bootlooping-t3640826/page6). For detailed about PON, refer to Qualcomm documentation about PON.

Comment: IIUC, if you call `device_create()` it's not enough to have device node. It will be sysfs node and kernel event, based on which `udev` or alike will create a device node on behalf of kernel.